# How to install i386 (32bit) boost-regex library to amd64 (64bit) system, 15.04

Tags: 15.04, 64-bit, regex, boost

I tried to use this command:
sudo apt-get install libboost-regex1.55-dev:i386

And i have some errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-regex1.55-dev:i386 : Depends: libboost1.55-dev:i386 (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score -3):

open the terminal 
then type:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

enter your password
then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

enter your password.

Comment: It doesn't help :(